# Upgrading to Entity Framework 6 from Entity Framework 5 (mixing and matching within solution)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a large solution with a number of Entity Framework sub projects.

Lets just say I have

**MySolution** (currently all EF 5)

- ProjectUi which references all of the 3 below
- ProjectData1.EF (which is using Entity Framework 5)
- ProjectData2.EF (which is using Entity Framework 5)
- ProjectData3.EF (which is using Entity Framework 5)

Now the actual solution has a lot more going on than this.

I'm wondering can I update ProjectData1.EF to Entity Framework 6 and leave the others using Entity Framework5, or do I have to do it all in one go.

So it will then be

**MySolution** (will be a mix and match)

- ProjectUi which references all of the 3 below
- ProjectData1.EF (which is now upgraded to use Entity Framework 6)
- ProjectData2.EF (which is using Entity Framework 5)
- ProjectData3.EF (which is using Entity Framework 5)

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Comment: @D Stanley I might just do that tomorrow if I get time, but would be interesting to know it is not possible before I go to the bother of trying to update my solution.

Comment: If they're going to share a DbContext at any point I would upgrade all of them at once.

Comment: As long as you are only using basic functionality it MAY work without problems. But I believe in keeping things consistent and I am pretty sure that you are asking for versioning trouble and different object if you keep different version within the same solution.

Comment: @DigitalD they won't shared a dbContext, do you think it is possible to upgrade them individually?  As we will have to do a full regression test for each EF. And it is expensive to do.

Comment: It might be possible. But it's still possible for _bad things_ (tm) to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say not as the EntityFramework.dll will clash on the differing versions when copied from the different projects into the output folder for ProjectUI.

Comment: Yeah when I tested it it completely crapped out.